# pip doesn't work after upgrading with pip-tools

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I use Ubuntu 14.10 x64, with both Python 2.7.6 (default) and 3.4.0.

After upgrading via pip-tools the packages:

```
$ pip install pip-tools
$ pip-review --interactive
```

If I call pip:

```
$ pip
```

I get:

```
user@computer:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

Ideas to fix the problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I've removed pip and then:

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
$ easy_install pip
```

Now everything works!